# DB2 toad "Commit" in another editor while one editor is running update query

Tags: sql, database, db2, commit, toad

In Toad, I opened one editor and pasted 10,000 records like "UPDATE AWBHISTORY SET USERID=2982 WHERE AWBHISTORYID=2586670;" like this I have 10,000 records. Forgot to add the commit also inbetween(automatic commit is Off). So I dont want to stop it inbetween. So I opened one more editor in the same Toad, And giving commit. Will it commit the updates what Im running on the same Toad in another editor..? My Toad version is 4.0.1.921. Thank You.

Comment: I am not familiar with toad, but I would definitely wait until the first one finishes and try to rollback.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I dont want to rollback. The query that Im running is correct. But I need to frequently commit the updates, Only then the System [web page] which is accessing this DB  will not be get any performance issues while my query is locking up the table.

Comment: but isn't it already running? you probably shouldn't run the same SQL while the other is running that could cause concurrent update problems which could result in a dead lock.

Comment: FInally it run without any problem. It took around 30 minutes. But system didnt face any performance Issues. Thank You for the reply.